# Add watermark like this image

Tags: shell, imagemagick

I want to use ImageMagick to add a watermark like the image bellow, how can I do this using only IM?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*use the following command:*

```
magick convert input.jpg -alpha set -background none ( -font arialbd.ttf -pointsize 55 -fill #ffffff80 -size 240x220 label:PROOF -write mpr:tile +delete ) ( -clone 0 -resize 300% -colorize 100 -tile mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" -rotate -40 -chop 50%x50% ) -composite output.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: For Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Answer (score 4):

With ImageMagick v6 in bash...

```
convert image.jpg -alpha set -background none -fill "#ffffff80" \
   \( -size 100x100  label:"PROOF" -rotate 45 -write mpr:tile +delete \) \
   \( +clone -tile mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) -composite result.png
```

For IMv7 use "magick" instead of "convert". For Windows change the continued-line backslashes "\" to carets "^", and remove the backslashes "\(...\)" that escape the parentheses "(...)".